# How to do page postback in popup windows?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, popup, postback

I'm working with an application develop by ASP.NET and jQuery, I have a popup screen implemented using jQuery client script to called the  ID to fade in the popup windows which contains ASP.NET controls.

It look similar with the demo in [Simple Model](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) and [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)

The ASP.NET DropDownList controls in the popup windows need to do page postback to get data from database.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddl" runat="server" 
 AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="doSomething()">
     <asp:ListItem Text="continued" Value="1" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="on hold" Value="2" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="finished" Value="3" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

My questions is, can I keep the popup windows while page postback? How possible can it be done? Do I need to use iframe or something? Please advise...

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest approach would be to only do a partial postback by wrapping the drop down in an UpdatePanel. See http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Dorababu742/drop-down-list-in-ajax-update-panel/